# Autosize-rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the [autosize-rails gem](https://github.com/calebthompson/autosize-rails) to create text boxes that automatically get bigger when filled. I installed the gem and bundled it.

```
gem 'autosize-rails
```

I then added this to my js.coffeescript file:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("textarea").autosize()
```

and finally my form looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :title, as: :text, input_html: { :class => "textarea" }%>
```

The forms still use the default scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with this gem, but it looks like you need to change `$("textarea")` to `$(".textarea")` in your coffeescript file.

Comment: Hmm, no doesn't change.

Comment: too bad, can you post the html?

Comment: Found my problem. For some reason specifying 'font-size' makes it stop working.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.